# combining hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make an autoclicker in autohotkey but can't get it to work.

I have some knowledge about autohotkey but it is not very much:

```
<^LButton::
Loop
{
SetMouseDelay 0.001
Click
If(GetKeyState("LButton","P")=0)
Break
}
```

It works with `<^LButton` as hotkey, but not `<^nLButton`.

Therefore I need help with hotkey-combinations.

I get the errorcode:

> Line Text: <^nLButtonSuspend
>   Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.

Comment: what is `nLbutton`? It gives error because there is no such key. What are you trying to achieve by changing `LButton` to `nLButton`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combinate Three keys as a Hotkey.

Click the Keys : [Ctrl] + [n] + [Lbutton] = Do a Action.

You can Try this:

example1.ahk

```
;#notrayicon
#SingleInstance force

^n::
GetKeyState, state, Lbutton
if state = D
{
Loop
{
send a
;SetMouseDelay 0.001
;Click
If(GetKeyState("LButton","P")=0)
Break
}
} else {
send b ;this codeline is only so that you can test it out in notepad. - you can remove this
}
Return

esc::exitapp
```

note : It is not perfect but the answer is close to your Question.